# How to discover all HTML meta tags using edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.WebCrawler

Tags: automation, meta-tags, crawler4j

I am completing a research project to catalogue all HTML meta tags used to describe scientific and academic journals, e.g. Dublin Core, open graph, prism, citation, biblio etc..

I am using `edu.uci.ics.crawler4j.crawler.WebCrawler` and have it working for a small number of seed URL's.

My issue is I need a larger list of seed URL's.

What options do I have?

Do I have to manually search the web looking for journal websites or can I use something similar to `crawler4j` to discover the seed sites?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generating good seeds is a general problem for the field of `Web-Crawling`, especially for **field-specific** tasks (such as only look at academic journals). In general, there are several options:

- Use a Open Web Directory (e.g. dmoz, ...) or a Journal-List (e.g. [Reuters List](http://ip-science.thomsonreuters.com/mjl/)) to harvest pre-categorized seed points for well-known journals.
- In theory, the big search engines have harvested a quite big portion of the WWW. You can try to perform *semi-automated* searches for pre-defined queries and process the hits. However, this might lead to some more complicated techniques in Web-Crawling (e.g. `focused crawling`)

An option would be:

- Use `crawler4j` to collect the Journal names from [Reuters](http://ip-science.thomsonreuters.com/mjl/) for the fields you like to investigate.
- For this purpose, you need to look at the Journal lists, e.g. the [business journal list](http://ip-science.thomsonreuters.com/cgi-bin/jrnlst/jlresults.cgi?PC=BC). Journal names are always in the `h4` tags, which can be easily extracted.
- After extracting the names, you only have to find out the corresponding URLs. For this purpose, you could use the search-engine approach above. With high probability, the first hit should be the Journal's web-page.